# LogStash Kafka output/input is not working

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, logstash-configuration

I try to use logstash with kafka broker. It can not integrated together.

Each version are,

- logstash 2.4
- kafka 0.8.2.2 with scala 2.10

The kafka input config file is:

```
input { 
  stdin{
  }      
}
output{
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }

  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => 10.120.16.202:6667,10.120.16.203:6667,10.120.16.204:6667'
    topic_id => "cephosd1"
  }
}
```

I can list topic cephosd1 from kafka.
The stdout could print out content, also.

But I can not read anything from kafka-console-consumer.sh .

Comment: Integration LogStash 2.3 or 2.4 with Kafka 0.8/0.9/0.10 is so hard, I would use RabbitMQ or Redis instead. When LogStash could integrated with Kafka, I will try later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a compatibility issue. If you check the [version compatibility matrix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-kafka.html) between Logstash, Kafka and the `kafka` output plugin, you'll see that the `kafka` output plugin in Logstash 2.4 uses the Kafka 0.9 client version.

If you have a Kafka broker 0.8.2.2, it is not compatible with the client version 0.9 (the other way around would be ok). You can either downgrade to Logstash 2.0 or upgrade your Kafka broker to 0.9.

Comment: Thanks Val. In logstash 2.4, default logstash-input-kafka is 2.0.9 and logstash-output-kafka is 2.0.5. It should be compatibility with Kafka 0.8.x.

Comment: Yes but not with Logstash 2.4 apparently

Comment: Sure, I check with 'bin/logstash-plugin list --verbose | grep kafka' under logstash 2.4.

Comment: Can you start logstash with the `--debug` flag and paste the relevant Logstash logs in your question?

Comment: Yes, I am using --debug.It seems that LogStash could connect Kafka, but can not send/receive message.

Comment: Can you share the output ?